# Automatic push on commit (on bitbucket repository)

Tags: ssh, authentication, deployment, git, ssh-keys

I have a website which commits to a git local repository all the changes done.

I need to **automatically push them directly from the web server to a remote Bitbucket repository**.

**The authentication method I use to do it is by passwordless SSH key stored on the Web Server**, but I think this could be not so secure.

So the question is... do you know a more secure (or simply better) method to automatically push changes from a Web Server to a Git-Bitbucket private repository?

Comment: Check out [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90853/how-can-i-run-ssh-add-automatically-without-password-prompt) on Unix & Linux

Comment: A passwordless key can be secure, if you put constraints on its usage on the bitbucket repository. See e.g. https://serverfault.com/questions/507878/limited-ssh-access-for-log-retrieval/507899#507899 and https://security.stackexchange.com/a/84203/13705 .